# Selectively transposing a large CSV

Tags: bash, perl, csv, awk, sed

I am working on some huge CSV files (> 500 MB) on a tty Linux. I have my data in this format:

```
A, XYZ
A, ZSY
A, TVT
B,  GHJ
B, XYZ
C,  XYZ
C, TVT
```

Output should be as follows.

```
A, XYZ, ZSY, TVT
B, GHJ, XYZ, nil
C, XYZ, TVT, nil
```

The first column works as a key, and transposes all the other corresponding rows into columns. I only have standard Unix tools (+ perl).

Is there any standard Unix solution to solve this pragmatically?

Comment: Always try to show your efforts too which you have put to solve the issue in your post in code tags.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I was trying to write a huge bash script on tty, before deleting it. Will make sure to post my efforts next time!

Comment: Please show the code of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the order of the output should be same as Input_file then following may help you here.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=", ";OFS=","}{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1] OFS $NF:$NF} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk '
BEGIN{  FS=", ";OFS=","  }
{
  a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1] OFS $NF:$NF
}
END{
  for(i in a){ print i,a[i] }
}' Input_file
```

***2nd Solution:*** In case you want output order should be same as Input_file's order then following may help you.

```
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=", ";OFS="," }
!b[$1]++{ c[++count]=$1   }
{
  a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1] OFS $NF:$NF
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){  print c[i],a[c[i]]  }
}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution for `awk`, depends on whether your data is sorted for the first column

**Sorted:**

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '{if(a!=$1){printf (a!="")?"\n"$1:$1;a=$1} printf "%s%s",OFS,$2}END{print}'
```

Brief explanation,

1. `if(a!=$1){printf (a!="")?"\n"$1:$1;a=$1}`: defined `a` and print it if it's not defined
2. `printf "%s%s",OFS,$2`: always print the following columns.

**Unsorted**

```
sort -sk1,1 file | awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '{if(a!=$1){printf (a!="")?"\n"$1:$1;a=$1} printf "%s%s",OFS,$2}END{print}'
```

Sorted the first column by using `sort -sk1,1`, then do the same job as sorted one.

Comment: You could remove `cat` in second solution and could use it with `sort` itself.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13, modified it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!! Next time I will make sure to post what I tried first!!

Comment: Never do `printf $N`, always do `printf "%s", $N` instead. Consider the difference when `$N` contains printf formatting chars like `%s`. What `END{print}` does is undefined by POSIX so in some awks it'll print the last record read, in others it'll print a null string, and in others it could do just about anything else. Finally - that script just cannot produce the desired output, try it.

Answer (score 0):

This just prints the values for each unique key as it finds it so you don't have to store the whole huge file in memory:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS  = "[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*"
    OFS = ", "
}
$1 != prev {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        prt()
    }
    prev = $1
}
{
    vals[++numVals] = $2
}
END {
    prt()
}
function prt(   numCols, colNr, val) {
    numCols = 3
    printf "%s", prev
    for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
        val = (colNr in vals ? vals[colNr] : "nil")
        printf "%s%s", OFS, val
    }
    print ""
    delete vals
    numVals = 0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
A, XYZ, ZSY, TVT
B, GHJ, XYZ, nil
C, XYZ, TVT, nil
```